# jq - Find a JSON object based on one of its values and get another value from it

Tags: json, jq

I've started using jq just very recently and I would like to know if something like this is even possible.

Example:

```
{
  "name": "device",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "address": [
    {
      "address": "10.1.2.3",
      "interface": "wlan1_wifi"
    },
    {
      "address": "10.1.2.5",
      "interface": "wlan2_link"
    },
    {
      "address": "10.1.2.4",
      "interface": "ether1"
    }
  ],
  "wireless": [
    {
      "name": "wlan1_wifi",
      "type": "5Ghz",
      "ssid": "wifi"
    },
    {
      "name": "wlan2_link",
      "type": "2Ghz",
      "ssid": "link"
    }
  ]
}
```

Firstly let's transform the example to this json object:

```
cat json | jq '. | {"name": ."name", "version": ."version", "wireless": [."wireless"[] | {"name": ."name", "type": ."type", "ssid": ."ssid"}]}'
{
  "name": "device",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "wireless": [
    {
      "name": "wlan1_wifi",
      "type": "5Ghz",
      "ssid": "wifi"
    },
    {
      "name": "wlan2_link",
      "type": "2Ghz",
      "ssid": "link"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now there's a problem. I need to assign an address to the `"wireless"` array. The address is stored in `"address"` array.

**So the question: is there a way of finding the right json object in `"address"` based on `"name"` (in wireless array) and "`interface"` (in address array) for every json object in `"wireless"` array and then assigning `"address"` to it?**

The final result should look like this:

```
{
  "name": "device",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "wireless": [
    {
      "name": "wlan1_wifi",
      "type": "5Ghz",
      "ssid": "wifi",
      "address": "10.1.2.3"
    },
    {
      "name": "wlan2_link",
      "type": "2Ghz",
      "ssid": "link",
      "address": "10.1.2.5"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Answer:**
Here's my answer based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51563052/5971350) from @peak. Instead of copying the content of `.wireless` and then using `map`, I'm  cherry picking the keys that I want to include only. This also allows me to position "address" how ever I want.

```
(INDEX(.address[]; .interface)) as $dict 
| {name: .name, version: .version, 
wireless: [.wireless[] | {name, address: ($dict[.name]|.address), type, ssid}]}
```

Comment: Please take the time to create a mininal example instead of dropping a bunch of real world data into the question

Comment: Josef - Yes, it’s possible, but see [mcve].

Comment: sorry @hek2mgl, now it should be alright

Comment: cool! looks much better now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following produces the output as originally requested:

```
(.wireless[].name) as $name
| .address[]
| select(.interface == $name)
| { wireless: {name: $name, address}}
```

However the above filter could potentially produce more than one result, so you might want to make modifications accordingly.

### Revised revised requirements

If your jq has `INDEX/2` (which was only made available AFTER jq 1.5 was released), you can simply use it to create a lookup table:

```
(INDEX(.address[]; .interface)) as $dict
| {name,
   version,
   wireless: (.wireless
              | map(. + {address: ($dict[.name]|.address) }) ) }
```

Or (depending perhaps on the exact requirements):

```
(INDEX(.address[]; .interface)) as $dict
| del(.address)
| .wireless |= map(. + {address: ($dict[.name]|.address) })
```

If your jq does not have `INDEX/2`, then you could easily adapt the above (using `reduce`), or even more easily snarf the def of `INDEX/2` from https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq

Comment: Thanks! This works for the minimal example, however I'm having trouble passing additional values from "wireless" array. Let's say each object in "wireless" array has additional key/value pair "ssid". How can I display that in the final output in "wireless" object? Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest adding an addendum to your original question, following the [mcve] guidelines again.

Comment: Where does "wifi" come from?  From the suffix of the .interface string?

Comment: No. It comes from the object in "wireless" array, so from the same place as "name" comes from. The value of the key can vary.

Comment: It looks like you have forgotten the [mcve] principles.

Comment: No. I just want to pass as many key/value pairs from the object in "wireless" and then assign address to it. That's all. I just probably can't express myself good enough.

Comment: I've modified the example a bit, hopefully it's clear what I'm trying to achieve now. Give it a shot, please :)

Comment: ok I accepted this answer way too soon. With one object in "wireless" it works ok, but if the input json has 2 or more objects in "wireless" it goes crazy. Please is there a solution that will work with 1 **and** more objects in "wireless"? Thanks!

Comment: It appears you ignored the explicit caveat. Yes, there is a solution, but you will need a more explicit set of requirements, and preferably a more informative example or test case.

Comment: In the original question I stated **"for every json object in "wireless" array"**. By that I meant a solution that will work with 1 and more objects. This is what happens when trying to keep the example minimal.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about INDEX until now. I updated the original question with answer that suits my particular use case better.

Comment: Any way you could add the input at the top of your answer? it's very difficult for me to figure out what the input is from the question