# How do you match the properties of one array of objects to the properties of another if they are both in arrays?

Tags: json, jq

Forgive me for the terrible title. [The jq manual has a section called "Variable / Symbolic Binding Operator"](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Advancedfeatures) that says this:

Suppose we have an array of blog posts, with "author" and "title" fields, and another object which is used to map author usernames to real names. Our input looks like:

```
{"posts": [{"title": "Frist psot", "author": "anon"},
           {"title": "A well-written article", "author": "person1"}],
 "realnames": {"anon": "Anonymous Coward",
               "person1": "Person McPherson"}}
```

We want to produce the posts with the author field containing a real name, as in:

```
{"title": "Frist psot", "author": "Anonymous Coward"}
{"title": "A well-written article", "author": "Person McPherson"}
```

We use a variable, $names, to store the realnames object, so that we can refer to it later when looking up author usernames:

```
.realnames as $names | .posts[] | {title, author: $names[.author]}
```

I want to the exact same output with a slightly different input: my "realnames" is an array of objects:

```
{"posts": [{"title": "Frist psot", "author": "anon"},
           {"title": "A well-written article", "author": "person1"}],
 "realnames": [{id: "anon", name: "Anonymous Coward"},
               {id: "person1", name: "Person McPherson"}]}
```

How would I get the exact same output from this input?

I *may* be asking this question, but I honestly can't tell because the question has so much noise in it: [jq - Find a JSON object based on one of its values and get another value from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51558701/jq-find-a-json-object-based-on-one-of-its-values-and-get-another-value-from-it) I think this is different: from what I can tell, the input only has one array)

Comment: You *are* asking that question. https://jqplay.org/s/RSwLczAXm7

Comment: @oguzismail Good to know.can you explain what this `.realnames[]; .id` syntax means? The official documentation does not mention you can do this.

Comment: Function arguments are separated by semicolons in JQ. `INDEX/2` takes two arguments; a stream and an index expression. `.realnames[]` is the stream, and `.id` is the latter.

Comment: okay but as far as I can tell, [index doesn't accept multiple arguments.](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions)

Comment: [It does](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#SQL-StyleOperators). There are two INDEX functions in JQ, one with an arity of 1, and the other with an arity of 2.

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of "How to Solve It", you could simply convert the format for .realnames that you have into the one you know how to use.

This could be accomplished via:

```
.realnames |= (map({(.id): .name}) | add)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this on my own:

Input:

```
{"posts": [{"title": "Frist psot", "author": "anon"},
           {"title": "A well-written article", "author": "person1"}],
 "realnames": [{"id": "anon", "name": "Anonymous Coward"},
               {"id": "person1", "name": "Person McPherson"}]}
```

Filter:

```
.realnames[] as $names | .posts[] | {title, author: (select(.author == $names.id) | $names.name)}
```

Output:

```
{
  "title": "Frist psot",
  "author": "Anonymous Coward"
}
{
  "title": "A well-written article",
  "author": "Person McPherson"
}
```